# Can't find a source file at "printf.c" error in eclipse

Tags: c

Can't find a source file at "printf.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location. 
i get this error when i try debugging the program but when i compile the program i get proper output i am working on C and i am using eclipse Galileo installed in ubuntu. How to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to debug a library function, `printf()`. Symbolic debugging of a function is only available when you have it's symbols, or it's source code. So, the solutions are as follows: (1) if you don't need to debug the library function, don't dive into it while debugging, i.e. use `step over` instead of `step into` style of the breakpoint advancement, (2) if you need to debug the library function, get it's source code, or it's symbols, and make them available to the IDE debugger.